# if else and session - how to stop both if's showing up?

Tags: php

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but after a selection is made in the dropdown from the first "if unset" if, the dropdown still shows up above the the new if's output.

Once a selection is made, it should go to "ukset" or "uknotset" and not show the dropdown again.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
        session_start();

        // if unset
        if(!isset($_SESSION['grant_access'])) {$_SESSION['grant_access'] = 'unset';}
        if($_SESSION['grant_access'] == 'unset') {
            echo '<p>Make your choice</p>';
            echo '<form action="" onchange="this.submit()" method="post">';
            echo '<select name="thecountry">';
                echo '<option>Choose</option>';
                echo '<option value="hello">Hello</option>';
                echo '<option value="goodbye">Goodbye</option>';
                echo '<option value="unsure">Unsure</option>';
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</form>';
            }

        // if UK is set
        if(isset($_POST['thecountry']) && ($_POST['thecountry'] == 'hello')) {$_SESSION['grant_access'] = 'ukset';}
        if($_SESSION['grant_access'] == 'ukset') {
            echo 'welcome';
            }

        // if UK is not set
        if(isset($_POST['thecountry']) && ($_POST['thecountry'] !== 'hello')) {$_SESSION['grant_access'] = 'uknotset';}
        if($_SESSION['grant_access'] == 'uknotset') {
            echo 'access denied';
            }   

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of the order you are changing sessions value. At first you set it to `unset` and show the form. Then, upon form submit your code runs, but since the session variable is still `unset` form is visible again.

Put your `$_POST` checks at the start of your code, for example like this:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
 // post check, change session value
}

// rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be simple!

Answer (score 1):

you should do **onchange** on the select box .check the code below

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // if UK is set
    if(isset($_POST['thecountry']) && ($_POST['thecountry'] == 'hello')) {$_SESSION['grant_access'] = 'ukset';}
    if(@$_SESSION['grant_access'] == 'ukset') {
        echo 'welcome';
        }

                // if UK is not set
    else if(isset($_POST['thecountry']) && ($_POST['thecountry'] !== 'hello')) {$_SESSION['grant_access'] = 'uknotset';}
    if(@$_SESSION['grant_access'] == 'uknotset') {
        echo 'access denied';
        }   


    // if unset
    else if(!isset($_SESSION['grant_access'])) {$_SESSION['grant_access'] = 'unset';}
    if($_SESSION['grant_access'] == 'unset') {
        echo '<p>Make your choice</p>';
        echo '<form action="" name="frm" id="frm"  method="post">';
        echo '<select name="thecountry" onchange="frm.submit()">';
            echo '<option>Choose</option>';
            echo '<option value="hello">Hello</option>';
            echo '<option value="goodbye">Goodbye</option>';
            echo '<option value="unsure">Unsure</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</form>';
        }
```

?>

Comment: did u checked the code i supplied caz i added the form id and name which u forget to add.i checked it and its working u can check with my code..